# Insert a number to a sorted linked list, why the number inserts to the second position every time?

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, insert, singly-linked-list

I am working on a project about linked list, I have trouble with inserting a number to a sorted linked list. The number inserted to the second position every time, I cannot figure out where the problem is.Here is my code:

```
void insertSort(struct linkedList *n,int num,int *length){                   //insert number to a sort linked list
    node *new = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));          //create a new node
    new->next=NULL;
    new->data = num;
    while(n!=NULL&&n->data > new->data){             // find which position     num should insert in sorted list
            n = n->next;
    }
    new->next = n->next;          
    n->next= new;       
    length += 1;

}
```

n is head of the linked list. I initialized head points to the first node and has not value.
Here is how I call this function:

```
insertSort(head->next,num,&length);
```

The number inserted to the second position every time. Like I want to insert 45 into sorted linked list <16,32,72,81,97>, after inserting, the list would be <16,45,32,72,81,97>. 45 inserts to the second position for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem :

> The number inserted to the second position every time...

is occurring because in this part of code:

```
while(n!=NULL&&n->data > new->data){             // find which position     num should insert in sorted list
        n = n->next;
}
new->next = n->next;          
n->next= new;
```

you are inserting the new node after the `n->next`.

Assume the first node of your linked list is having data `16` and now you want to insert the new node with data `45` in the linked list, the `while` loop condition will fail as `16 > 45` will evaluate to `false`.

And the statement after `while` loop `new->next = n->next;` will set the next of new node to next of the first node and `n->next= new;` will insert the new node after first node. Hence, the new node inserted to second position every time.

There are few more problems with your function `insertSort()` like:

- It does not track the `head` of the linked list while inserting a node to the linked list and,
- What will happen if the node inserted is the first node of the linked list? In that case `n` will `NULL` and in `insertSort()` after `while` loop it is accessing `next` of `n` - `new->next = n->next;`.

Looking at the example you have given - <16,32,72,81,97>, you want to insert in ascending order.
You can do:

```
struct linkedList *insertSort(struct linkedList *n, int num, int *length) {
    struct linkedList *first_node = n;

    struct linkedList *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));  //create a new node
    new_node->next=NULL;
    new_node->data = num;

    if (first_node == NULL || first_node->data >= new_node->data) {
            new_node->next = first_node;
            first_node = new_node;
    } else {
            struct linkedList *temp = first_node;

            while (temp->next != NULL && temp->next->data < new_node->data) {
                    temp = temp->next;
            }
            new_node->next = temp->next;
            temp->next = new_node;
    }
    *length += 1;

    return first_node;
}
```

Here, you can see that I have changed return type `void` to `struct linkedList *` so that after inserting new node to appropriate location in linked list `insertSort()` will return the `head` of the linked list. That way you can keep track of `head` of linked list after every insertion. You just need to do:

```
head = insertSort(head, num, &length);
```

from wherever you are calling `insertSort()`.

Alternatively, you can pass the address of `head` pointer in `insertSort()` and keep track of it, if you don't want to change the return type of `insertSort()`, like this:

```
void insertSort(struct linkedList **head, int num, int *length) {
    struct linkedList *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));  //create a new node
    new_node->next=NULL;
    new_node->data = num;

    if (*head == NULL || (*head)->data >= new_node->data) {
        new_node->next = *head;
        *head = new_node;
    } else {
        struct linkedList *temp = *head;

        while (temp->next != NULL && temp->next->data < new_node->data) {
                temp = temp->next;
        }
        new_node->next = temp->next;
        temp->next = new_node;
    }
    *length += 1;
}
```

You can call `insertSort()` like this:

```
insertSort(&head, 32, &length);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: "It does not track the head of the linked list while inserting a node to the linked list". just wandering why we need to track the head of linked list. Isn't head always pointing to the first node. Like if I insert 2 to <1,3>, which gives us<1,2,3>. Head is always pointing to the first node, no matter what value it is. So, tracking the position of the head does not make sense to me. Thank you for answering!

Comment: Let's assume you have list `<1,2,3>` and the `head` is pointing to the first node i.e. `1`. Now, try inserting `0` to list `<1,2,3>`. The resultant list will be `<0,1,2,3>` and the `head`, which was earlier pointing to node `1`, should now point to node `0`. That's why the list insertion logic needs to set/reset the `head` of the list based on the new element you want to insert in the list so that the `head` should always point to the first element in the list.

Comment: So I can pass the address of head, which is a pointer to pointer.

Comment: like insertSort(int linkedList **n, int num, int *length)

Comment: Yes, with this you can simply set/reset head pointer `*n` based on the condition.

Comment: so, if I do  insertSort(int linkedList **n, int num, int *length), do I need to change every n to *n(like n->data to (n*)->data, n->next to (*n)->next) since we passed a pointer to pointer. Plus, when I call this function. Is insertSort(&(*head), num,&length) or (&head,num,&length)

Comment: "_do I need to change every n to *n_" -> No. Since `n` contains the address of `head`, so you need to do `*n` only when the `head` pointer needs to reset. Whenever you need to parse the list, take a local variable and initialize it to the head of the list and parse it. I have updated my answer and added insertion function with passing the head reference. Hope that clears your doubt.

Comment: Awesome! I understand much more right now! Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

because you are never testing the position of the node . your code only puts the new node at 2nd position . it does not checks where it should be in the sorted list 
try below

```
 void sortedInsert(struct Node** head_ref, struct Node* new_node) {

        struct Node* current;   /* Special case for the head end */ 
        if(*head_ref == NULL || (*head_ref)->data >= new_node->data)    {

            new_node->next = *head_ref;         
            *head_ref = new_node;   
        } 
        else    { 
        /*Locate the node before the point of insertion */      
            current =*head_ref;            
            while (current->next!=NULL && current->next->data < new_node->data) 
           {            
              current = current->next;  
         }        
           new_node->next =current->next;   
           current->next = new_node;    }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering why we have to check the position of the node. For example, <1->3->5>. now I am inserting 2 to the list. So we make 1 pointing to 2, and 2 pointing to 3, which gives us<1->2->3->5>. I am not sure why we check the position for.

Comment: because you might next time insert 4 in the list . the code needs to find where is the last smaller value then 4 , in this case its 3 . looking for position works with n sized of list .