# Printing a Linked List, doesn't print anything

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list of students and their IDs.
I think everything is ok except from the List* head in the functions.
I am not good with functions so i don't know if its right.

When i try to print all students it doesn't give any output it just returns back to the instruction (goes through main loop again without printing the names).
Can you please help me.

To me it looks like the head is not kept the same throughout each function and in main so the printing doesn't occur but i can't figure out how to fix this.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <malloc.h>
   #include <string.h>



   typedef struct node
    {
      char name[50];
      int ID;
      node *next;
    }
      List;

   void Linked_insert(char givenname[50], int givenID, int start, List* head)
    {
       //if its the users first time inserting start becomes 0 and if it isnt start is 1 so for both cases i made that condition 
      if(start==0){    
       strcpy(head->name, givenname);
       head->ID = givenID;
       head->next = NULL;
       return head;
        }
      if(start==1){
       //end of list

        List* current = head;
           while(current->next != NULL){
           current = current->next;
           }
        current->next = malloc(sizeof(List));
        strcpy(current->next->name, givenname);
        current->next->ID = givenID;
        current->next->next = NULL;
        return current->next;
        }

     }



    void Linked_destroy()
     {

     }

    void Print_student(List* head)
     {
     }

    void Print_all(List* head)
       {    
         List* current = head;
           while(current->next != NULL){
           printf("Student ID [%d] has name [%s]\n", current->ID, current->name);
           current = current->next;    
            }
        }

     int main()
     {
        int loop=0, start=0;
          while(loop != 1)
            {
              printf("\n\n\n\n");
              printf("Data Structures - Linked List and Binary Tree\n");
              printf("Choose one Option:\n\n");
              printf("1.Insert Student\n");
              printf("2.Remove Student\n");
              printf("3.Print 1 student\n");
              printf("4.Print all student\n");
              printf("5.Exit\n\n");
              int option=0, inputID;
              char inputname[50];
               List* head = malloc(sizeof(List));
               scanf("%d", &option);
                 switch(option)
                   {
                     case 1:
                      printf("Enter Student name:   ");
                      scanf("%s", inputname);
                      printf("Enter Student ID:     ");
                      scanf("%d", &inputID);
                      Linked_insert(inputname, inputID, start, head);
                      start = 1;
                       break;

                      case 2:

                        break;

                      case 3:

                        break;

                      case 4:
                        Print_all(head);
                        break;

                      case 5:
                        loop =1;
                        break;

                      default:
                        loop =1;
                        break;

                  }//end of switch

           }//end of infinte loop
    }//end of main
```

Comment: doesn't compile, either

Comment: i dont know what to put instead of void. also i am not sure how to update head thats why i am asking here

Comment: many, many problems beginning from the ground. From wrong type name (not List, suggest ListItem). Broken list implementation (`head` role hard to udenrstand)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring because you are allocating memory to `head` of list in every iteration of `while` loop:

```
while(loop != 1)
.....
.....
    List* head = malloc(sizeof(List));
```

In every iteration of while loop the new `head` of list is getting created and the old `head` reference is getting lost (memory leak). 
Move the `head` node memory allocation before entering the while loop.

The another problem is in the function `Print_all()` which will not print the last node of the list:

```
while(current->next != NULL){
```

this should be

```
while(current != NULL){
```

There are few more issues in your code, like `Linked_insert()` return type is `void` but it is returning some value. Compiler must be giving error on those `return` statements.

Also, you are not freeing the memory allocated dynamically to the list nodes. Follow good programming practice, once you are done with list you should free all the nodes of list.

Comment: @Gerhardh which function?

Comment: @Gerhardh memory to `head` is allocated in `main()` inside the `while` loop and then it is passed to `Linked_insert()` --> `Linked_insert(inputname, inputID, start, head);`. I do not agree with your this statement --> _Whatever you assign will be lost after the function is left._

Comment: I am sorry. I confused the loop in `main` with the loop in `Linked_insert`. You are right.

Comment: @Gerhardh may you also want to correct your comment on OP question - _Also inserting does not work...._

Comment: @EEECS Your `Linked_insert()` function is having statements - `return head;` and `return current->next;` which means you are trying to return `List *` type from `Linked_insert()` function. Since you are passing the reference of `head` to `Linked_insert()` function and adding new elements at the end of list so, you dont need to return `List *` from your function because `head` of list never going to change. Consider case where you want to insert to you linked list in sorted order. _...continue in next comment_

Comment: In such case it is possible that the `head` of list may change and you want your insert function to return the `head` of list. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47234071/8542346). Seems that you are learning the list, check [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47654433/8542346) for reference.